# Is it possible to tell a element to 'derive width from grandparent'?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a some items that I want to display in a centered column, and I want them to be able to determine their own width: either a fixed pixel value, or 'full width' type value.

Ordinarily, either a flexbox parent with 'align-self: stretch' on the child (as per the second example in the code snippet), or not flexbox and just using 'margin: 0 auto' to center works, .

However, I also want to be able to wrap these components in a button-like div that has click handlers, hover states etc.

In this scenario the 'align-self: stretch' trick stops working.

```css
.grandparent {
  border: dashed 1px black;
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  border: solid grey 2px;
}

.flex-container:hover {
  border-color: purple;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.i-have-fixed-width {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #ddf;
}

.i-want-to-be-full-width {
  background-color: #fdd;
  align-self: stretch; // does not work
}
```

```html
<p> With the flex container wrappers (width is lost):</p>

<div class="grandparent">

  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="i-want-to-be-full-width">
      I want to be full width
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="i-have-fixed-width">
      I have fixed width:
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<p> Directly nested in grandparent (Behaves correctly):</p>


<div class="grandparent">

  <div class="i-want-to-be-full-width">
    I want to be full width
  </div>
  <div class="i-have-fixed-width">
    I have fixed width:
  </div>

</div>
```

Is there a way to achieve what I want here?

Comment: *I also want to be able to wrap these components in a button-like div that has click handlers, hover states etc.* --> why not simply adding a class to them instead of wrapping them

Comment: @TemaniAfif  That is is something that I considered. But the problem is it would require that the underlying component supports all of the props that I'm passing through - and any aria-label for example would be clobbered by the one I'm passing in.